# Carbon monoxide formation in broken boilers

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, safety, toxicity

It's common knowledge, that if you're boiler is broken, it might produce carbon monoxide ($\ce{CO}$) as a byproduct, which is very toxic, even in small quantities. My question is, why do broken boilers do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combustion of hydrocarbons works as follows:

$\ce{hydrocarbon + O2-> CO + H2O}$

The reaction can then continue to the complete combustion:

$\ce{CO + 1/2 O2-> CO2}$

An example of balanced equation is the combustion of methane:

1. $\ce{CH4 +  3/2O2 -> CO + 2H2O}$
2. $\ce{CO +  1/2O2 -> CO2}$

**So, carbon monoxide is a product of the incomplete combustion of a hydrocarbon.**

It is produced when there is too much fuel (eg: methane), but not enough oxidant (eg: oxygen from air).

I guess that a boiler which cannot mix properly air and fuel produces carbon monoxide.

Comment: And when/why does the reaction stop at the first stage?

Comment: It does not really stop at the first step. Both steps will occur but **overall** there is not enough oxygen to convert everything to carbon dioxide.